# How do you set MAILTO in crontab programmatically?

Tags: unix, cron

I am currently creating my crontab programmatically as follows:

```
echo "* * * * * run_some_job" | crontab -
```

Additionally, I want to **programmatically** set the `MAILTO` address, is that possible? That is, without the interactive editor `crontab -e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crontab can take multi line input.
So, give two lines, for example this way:

```
> (echo "MAILTO=xxx@yyy.org"; echo "* * * * * run_some_job") | crontab -

> crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Fri Jan 24 16:26:20 2020)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
MAILTO=xxx@yyy.org
* * * * * run_some_job
```

And programmatically (because of unix-tag, C example):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE* file = popen("/usr/bin/crontab -", "w");
    if (file)
    {
       fprintf(file, "MAILTO=xxx@yyy.org\n");
       fprintf(file, "10 11 * * * run_some_job\n");
       pclose(file);
    }
}
```

result:

```
> gcc main.c
> ./a.out 
> crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Fri Jan 24 16:35:03 2020)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
MAILTO=xxx@yyy.org
10 11 * * * run_some_job
```